# Hair offset when view is rotated

Tags: rendering, rigging, particles, hair

Hair was fine, pivot was fine ... changed view from front to side ... notice how all child objects move on other pivots

[image]

some times the rigging jumps out the mesh and becomes all twisted

Sorry it took so long to get this back

[image]

Comment: Hierarchy in modifiers? Hard to detect without blend file.  You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: well that sight may have a bug won't accept upload

Comment: well after i wrote this it finally uploaded but wouldn't keep it. It stated that blend files could be no more  than 30 mb.  this small  blend  reads 91mb any other place an upload may work

Comment: Simplify the file. You can delete all unrelated objects, materials etc. ... just keep objects that still produce the issue. Sometimes textures take a lot of space. Deleted material sometimes is kept as orphaned data, so delete these or open a new file and "Append" hair obect (with armature). Or use wetransfer.com and share link I can try upload simplified file later. BTW any reason to use 2.7x version? Graphics card?

Comment: Sorry it took so long this is the reduced file containing just the particle hair system

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=GZdVxn7m" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/GZdVxn7m/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I can help. On my iMac behaviour is much weird than on your.

[image]

But definitely is incorrect dimensions you operate with - Location of your object in your file is
X = 119 Y = 448 Z = -28 (miles)

**Clear Location** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> brings object to zero coordinates, it fixed glitching.

[image]

Than I wanted *Apply Scale* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> that is always recommended, but it doesn't worked as supposed to. It brings scale to one as, but Dimension jumped back to original object scale (5 miles).

I had to use **Apply Scale Deltas**.

So try those steps if they help in your case as well.
From your *View > Clip > End* 1893939412 miles I see you fight with scale/dimension. In general - it is always better to Apply Scale. Also you have set in Scene Properties > Units > 0.0254 that is something I don't know what represent (since 1 km = 0.62137119224 mi), but I never used this feature.

After all this, when I tried add Hair Children worked fine.

---

*BTW opening your file in 2.9x is even crazier disco :)*

Comment: thanks for responding. your right that will in the present cause things to appear better but the problem is by the time I'm finished with my blends there will be a lot more data present so i looking for how do i stop the random behaviors from occurring

Comment: Hi (⁠•⁠‿⁠•⁠) if the answer solved your question it is common to [mark it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour). Thank you keep this site organized. To your comment - I don't think I understood what do you want to say, sorry. If you have another question please crate a new thread for it with more details. Thanks (⁠•⁠‿⁠•⁠)

Comment: well i'll try to respond in order 2.72 becuse of it nature and it has the best graphic on it splash screen. it causes the mind to move into a creative mode as opposted to the others that are completed and well defined works

Comment: Blender has been used to make some pretty large games. that's not a real 5 miles just a plot on a graph. that i left some verts. so if it OK I'ld like to leave it open until a more complete answer as to how  this happened and how to fix it comes. Other than that I'm left deleting everything or transferring ever peace to a new blend making blends that are uselessly small etc...

Comment: Sure, your choice :), but I don't think you get more info here ... the issue is definitely the scale you operate with ... there is a plety of issues caused by this kind of large scales scenes. You can try to search for similar threads and the only one solution that worked was scale it down or move it closer to world origin. If you want to attract more people here you can set a Bounty to your Q, but I don't know if that is possible for your current credit 1, but you can answer some simple Q here to reach 50 (just a 5 upvotes to your answers does that). Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you  a bunch I'll give it some consideration